# How can i make alias for searching text inside files in linux

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I want to make my custom alias for searching text inside the directory recursively.
Currently i use this

```
grep -r "text to search" /var/www/sites
```

I want first

1. To search only specific files like only html , php files only.
2. I also want the line number of the file
3. i want to make the alias of command like  `myalias`
   so that from command line i use only this

`myalias  text-to-search  (without quotes)`

Is this possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in your ~/.bashrc:

```
wwwgrep() { 
    find /var/www/sites -name '*.php' -o -name '*.html' -exec grep -Hn "$1" {} \;
}
```

Then

```
wwwgrep <PATTERN>
```

Finally (to refresh your environment)

```
exec bash
```

Comment: There was an error, it's ok now. typo with `-p` switch instead of `-n` for `grep`

Comment: You have to `source ~/.bashrc` when you have finish to edit the file.

Comment: or logout and login so that .bashrc gets executed.

Comment: @sputnick I have found that its not telling me the name of file , only line number and matched text. can u have a look please

Comment: Post edited accordingly. But a 10sec search in `man grep` would you informed.

Comment: @thanks buddy , Actually i was not sure if i fault was with find or grep. But i will take care next time